# How can we set a model is as default=0 or default=null in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Two month back I had created two models and it was working well, and now these models have lot of query which is filled by users. It is clear that both models are independent to each other.

My previous **models.py**

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    state_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,unique=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_all_states(self):
        return State.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name

class College(models.Model):
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    college_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,unique=True)
    university_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.college_name
```

Today I want to design College model according to state wise. If users have selected some state than related college list will come. For this condition I have created below **models.py**

```
class State(models.Model):
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    state_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,unique=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_all_states(self):
        return State.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name

class College(models.Model):
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    college_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False,unique=True)
    university_name = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    state_id = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @classmethod
    def get_all_colleges(self):
        return self.College.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.college_name
```

In code you can see state_id (in College models) is a foreign key. When I did migration then It's showing the error

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'state_id' to college without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
```

I tried to put default=null but it's showing error like can't do it, I also tried with default=0 but it's showing migration error ('app', College).

```
state_id = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
state_id = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=null)
```

1. How can we fix it?
2. Can we put default=null or default=0 in state_id objects?
3. If not then alternatively What would be the solution?
4. I got some solution on search but they are telling delete the table or cleared the College table data and then try to migrate again, but this will work when we are trying on localhost. What if we are trying on production server?

Comment: No, For fields like ForeignKey that map to model instances, defaults should be the value of the field they reference (`pk` unless `to_field` is set) instead of model instances. So you should provide the exists `pk` or use `null=True`.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: @NKSM Getting error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor'`

Comment: Don't use `state_id` or similar `..._id`  because, behind the scenes, Django appends **"_id"** to the field name to create its database column name, see [**Django ForeignKey**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#database-representation).

Comment: If you next error is not solved, please share **full traceback**.

Comment: @NKSM click [here](https://codeshare.io/5PvW8Y) to check traceback when I follow your steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this error because you already have rows in your database and you are trying to create a new column that must not be empty without specifying a value that will be inserted in already existing rows. When building the migration file, django should ask you what value you would like to set for this field for already existing rows when running `python manage.py makemigrations`.

However if you prefer not to set a default value but allow the `state_id` field to be empty, you should set `null=True` in your foreign key definition.

Comment: getting error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column app_college.state_id_id does not exist`

Comment: First, for foreign key you should not end the attribute by "id" as django will probably append "_id" to the database field.

Comment: Then, when did you get this error ? What were you doing ? Making migrations ?

Comment: When I click in one of the college list from django admin

Comment: Have you run a database migration first ? This is required to actually add the column in database. For the moment I suppose it is only defined in your code but does not exist yet in your database.

Comment: yea I have run migration first.

Comment: Then maybe check directly within your database whether the column actually exists or not ? Like with command line tools

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232145/discussion-between-kwall-and-alextorx).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have data in the table you will need to add an attribute to the model field null=True and do the migrations. The field should look like,

```
state_id = models.ForeignKey(State, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Doing this will no more show you add default error.

And in production what you can do is again leave it null and create the relation manually.

For eg: if you are creating a profile table to an existing user table you can run a condition checking if the user has a profile if not create one.

See the documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/